# How to use window.print() in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've followed [Getting the source HTML of the current page from Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension) to get HTML source from current page, and I modified the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` function like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
        message.innerText = request.source;
        //my code
        window.print();
    }
});
```

But `window.print()` does not work, can you please help me correct it?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Comment: In which file are you invoking print? It must be within the content script, not the background task.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reversed for print.
Change "print.window()" to the following:

```
window.print();
```

Comment: thank you, but still not work, :(

Answer (score -1):

You need a timeout before calling print.

You may use the code snippet as work around:
   `window.print();` 
    `setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 10000);` 
    `//give them 10 seconds to print, then close`

For your reference, please follow the link below:
[Print function in Chrome no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240001/print-function-in-chrome-no-longer-working)