# Print HTML works in IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

When I run through the JS in developer tools, it shows all the data from the innerHTML but the print only shows blank pages with the date. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
function PrintThisPage(sectionName) {
var sOption = "toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,";
sOption += "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,width=750,height=600,left=100,top=25";

var sWinHTML = document.getElementById(sectionName).innerHTML;
var winprint = window.open("", "", sOption);
winprint.document.open();
winprint.document.write('<html><head>');
winprint.document.write('<LINK href="../stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
winprint.document.write('<LINK href="../stylesheets/FormEdit.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
winprint.document.write('</head>')
winprint.document.write('<body style="display:none">');
winprint.document.write(sWinHTML);

arrInputs = winprint.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
    if (arrInputs[i].type == "image" || arrInputs[i].type == "button" || arrInputs[i].type == "submit") {
        arrInputs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

arrInputs = winprint.document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
    arrInputs[i].onmouseover = null;
}

winprint.document.write('</body></html>');
winprint.document.body.style.display = '';
winprint.document.close();

if (window.print) {
    winprint.print();
}
else {
    alert("Sorry, the print ready feature is only available in certain browsers.");
} // end - if (window.print)
```

}

**Edit**

```
imgPrint.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("PrintThisPage('{0}');",       divDataContent.ClientID);
```

When I run this in chrome, I get an exception: {System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot get inner content of divDataContent because the contents are not literal.

**Edit 2**

I receive the same error in IE, but the functionality still works.

**Edit 3**

Apparently Chrome doesn't like document.write, so I modified it to document.body/head.innerHTML.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why are you printing the DOM in JS?

Comment: He's taking DOM and printing it into a separate window.

Comment: Very old inherited app

Comment: Can you make a snip of this to help debug?

Comment: Is there a way outside of Snip It? Extensions are locked down.

Comment: You should not treat using document.write like building a string. Build up the string, than use one document.write line. Next you are referencing the new window and doing DOM manipulations before you event close the document.... Build the html as as string, write it to the page, do the DOM lookups.

Comment: Did you try this solution given by alaa-kh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240001/print-function-in-chrome-no-longer-working