# Webpage print is not woking

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In my website, if I click on the print button which is

```
<button class="btn btn-success float-right print_btn" onclick="window.print()">
<i class="fas fa-print">
</i><span class="bold">Print</span>
</button>
```

it's showing nothing after updating chrome 77. and on the console if I use `window.print();` it is showing `undefined` why so?

> I have also noticed one thing that if I copy the link and paste in
>   another tab it's working fine. but the link is dynamically generated.

[image]

Comment: Hi rahul, the onclick event is working for you? why am asking you is I copied your code and tried with same chrome version it works for me. Please check your chrome settings if the javascript is enabled or not?

Comment: no, it is not working

Comment: This question was already answered on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240001/print-function-in-chrome-no-longer-working) please refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it in chrome settings if the javascript is enabled or blocked? If it is blocked please allow the javascript in your browser.

```
"chrome://settings/content/javascript"
```

[image]

Comment: no sites are blocked in my browser. the same thing is working on firefox as well as opera

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was working on my local version but not on the production URL. I checked site settings to make sure it wasn't blocking anything:

- `chrome://settings/content/javascript`
- `chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

I did notice that pop-ups were blocked, so I reloaded the tab as requested but it still didn't work. I deleted my session and that didn't work. Finally I restarted Chrome and that worked.

Incidentally, when it wasn't working `window.print();` immediately returned `undefined` in the console. Once I got it working `window.print();` launched the dialog and cancelling it returned `undefined` in the console.